# #1054 - Unknown column 'content_type_video.field_video_file_fid' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, drupal-6

The following query returns the error above. I assume it's an aliasing error, because the column is there, but I can't figure it out from other posts on this error/topic. The query works fine until I add lines 11 and 21. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
    node.uid AS uid,
    node.nid AS nid,
    node.vid AS vid, 
    node.title AS post_title,
    node_revisions.body AS post_content,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created) AS post_date,
    users.name AS post_author,
    content_field_date.field_date_value AS publish_date,
    content_type_article.field_article_publication_value AS publication_name,
    content_type_video.field_video_file_fid AS fid,
    term_node.tid AS tid
FROM node node
LEFT JOIN node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid
LEFT JOIN users ON node.uid = users.uid
LEFT JOIN content_field_date ON content_field_date.nid = node.nid
LEFT JOIN content_type_article ON content_type_article.nid = node.nid
LEFT JOIN term_node ON term_node.nid = node.nid
LEFT JOIN files ON files.fid = content_type_video.field_video_file_fid 
WHERE 1
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't join a table called `content_type_video` wich you refer in the join condition